# Parametric random number generation with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, parameters

I was wondering if it is possible to generate a random distribution that is a function of a certain parameter. In other words, using MATLAB I type `rand(1,5)` I have a uniformly random distribution of 5 numbers between 0 and 1. It is possible to have this result as a function of a certain parameter? Do you know any algorithm about that? I just need that in an interval don't need a 2D representation.

Comment: "as a function" ...how exactly? Can you give an example of your expected input/output?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis for instance supposing that exist a function of a certain parameter and also function of a total number of values that I want in my `[0,1]` domain. So `f(a,N)` that given a value for `a` gives a certain random number distribution: `f(1,3) -> 0.256 0.434 0.876`. Instead for instance: `f(1.5,3) -> 0.342 0.573 0.972`. I'm looking for something like that if it exists

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to do this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

In MATLAB, it's quite straightforward, you simply specify the function.

```
n = 10000;         % number of random draws
r = rand(n, 1);    % generate uniform random numbers

f = @norminv;      % specify transforming function
tr = f(r);         % transformed numbers, now normally distributed
hist(tr, 30)       % plot histogram
```

This example is a bit contrived, since we could simply have used `randn`. But the method holds generally.
If you have the Statistics toolbox, and you want to sample from one of the popular distributions, take a look at the random number generators that are available to you, [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html#probability-distributions).

Comment: I can see `n` but where is my parameter? I'm looking for a random generation with `f(a,N)`.

Comment: The number of parameters doesn't really matter. After the numbers are transformed, that's all you need. For example, consider `f = @(x) norminv(x,10,5)`, which will transform to normal distribution centered at 10 with sigma 5.

Comment: that's interesting, I could use `sigma` as a parameter. Does the rand function gives me always numbers in `[0,1]`?

Comment: @Nicholas try using the help by means of:`help rand` for this kind of questions.